# NextAuth / Auth.js + Keycloak OAuthCallbackError: failed to validate JWT signature (T3 Stack)

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, keycloak, next-auth

I am attempting to integrate a remote Keycloak provider into my containerized Next application. Currently, I am able to make it all the way through the authentication flow, including reaching the correct Keycloak instance and signing in on that page, up until I *should* be signed into my app... At that point, I receive this error:

```
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_error failed to validate JWT signature { 
  error: RPError: failed to validate JWT signature 
    at Client.validateJWT (/app/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:1055:11) 
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) 
    at async Client.validateIdToken (/app/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:745:49) 
    at async Client.callback (/app/node_modules/openid-client/lib/client.js:488:7) 
    at async oAuthCallback (/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/oauth/callback.js:127:16) 
    at async Object.callback (/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:52:11)     
    at async AuthHandler (/app/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:201:28) 
    at async NextAuthHandler (/app/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:23:19)     
    at async /app/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:59:32 
    at async Object.apiResolver (/app/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:366:9) { 
  name: 'OAuthCallbackError', 
  code: undefined 
 }, 
 providerId: 'keycloak', 
 message: 'failed to validate JWT signature' 
}
```

I also have a Github app integrated with the application, and it works perfectly. the code for my [...nextauth].ts can be found below.

```js
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: env.KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: env.KEYCLOAK_ISSUER,
    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: env.GITHUB_ID || "",
      clientSecret: env.GITHUB_SECRET || "",
    }),
  ],
  debug: true,
  secret: env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

This is what my _app.tsx looks like:

```js
const MyApp: AppType<{ session: Session | null }> = ({
  Component,
  pageProps: { session, ...pageProps },
}) => {
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
};

export default trpc.withTRPC(MyApp);
```

And finally, my Login Button component:

```js
export default function LoginButton() {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        Signed in as {session.user?.name} <br />
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
      Not signed in <br />
      <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

I have gotten this integration to work before on a local containerized version of Keycloak using the `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.x.x` version of Keycloak, but have yet to get it to work with a remote/production version. The production version of Keycloak I am attempting to connect to is behind an NGINX reverse proxy, the configuration for which is fairly standard but can be provided upon request. I have even gone as far as to put the Next app and Keycloak into the same docker-compose file, to no avail.

I have attempted to change the location of the Next app, change the location of Keycloak, create a new app, create a new KC Realm, and integrate with other OAuth providers. I have never gotten further in the flow than the OAuthCallbackError, except when both versions were local, which is not acceptable for a production environment.

Has anyone else had this issue or found a possible fix?